# MAMP on Yosemite - connection error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdo, mamp

I know that I have seen this question before but have not seen an answer that has been able to fix the issue on my machine.

I'm relatively new to PHP and have no experience with Apache settings.

I am using the latest version of MAMP (not pro) with all the default settings on the latest version of OS X (10.3.3).

When I try to connect via PDO I receive the following error:

Unable to connect to the database server.exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resources/config.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/resources/config.php(7): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WEBSITE/index.php(2): include_once('/Applications/M...') #2 {main}

The connection code is from Kevin Yank's Novice to Ninja book, modified to apply to my database, username, etc.

```
try
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $DBUser,$DBPass);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{

  $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e;
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}
```

I have tried localhost and 127.0.0.1 and get the same error regardless.

I don't see anything in Console that could help but I may not be looking for the right thing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi,  Yes, I see mysqld running in Activity Monitor. It is under my user name.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My method was port but I didn't include the port number in the code. I had tried previously including it but used the Apache port instead of the MySQL port. Working like a charm now.

Answer (score 4):

try this command in mac

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I have the same issue on my mac and I run your given line, it works. Great! Thanks

Comment: same issue and it worked perfectly. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if `mysqld` is not running (stuff happens). It could also happen if you have a configuration error.

For example, on my installation, i reproduce the error with this DSN :

```
mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysqle.sock;dbname=notifications;charset=utf8
```

the config calls for `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Check the config to see what method is configured (port or socket) and which (port or socket). If you have the wrong port or socket in your DSN, you will produce the same error report in the question.